# If column value = NO don't display

Tags: php, if-statement

I have an if statement

```
<p>Included Services</p>
<?php foreach($services as $service): ?>  
<?php if(!empty($service['service_webdesign'])){ ?>
<div><strong>web Design:</strong> <?php echo $service['service_webdesign'] ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach ?>

<p>Services charged by the hour</p>
<?php foreach($services as $service): ?>  
<?php if(!empty($service['service_webdesign'])){ ?>
<div><strong>Service:</strong> <?php echo $service['service_webdesign'] ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

There are three possible values Yes, hourly rate or no.

In the first block I want to be able to echo the service column values

```
<div><strong>Service:</strong> <?php echo $service['service_webdesign'] ?></div>
```

only if the database value is 'yes'.

In the second block I want to echo the service fee column

```
<div><strong>Web Design:</strong> <?php echo $service['service_fee_webdesign'] ?>
</div>
```

only if the value of the 'service_webdesign' is set to 'hourly rate' but I do not actually want to show the value of 'service_webdesign' ('hourly rate').

An example of my database table structure is as follows

```
service_webdesign = Yes
service_fee_webdesign = NULL
service_graphicdesign = Hourly
service_fee_graphicdesign = 20
```

How can I achieve that within an if statement? Or would I need to create another SQL query for each of the blocks?

Comment: Great! But do you have any question at all?

Comment: why not simply exclude "No" results in the initial query?

Comment: Just a code comment, you don't need to wrap every line in <?php ?>. Just wrap the PHP lines. Makes it more readable.

Comment: @Takarii - I could do that I guess. But that won't separate the Yes values from the hourly rate values and display them in the different sections as I would like.

Comment: What holds the values your checking - $service['service_webdesign']?

Comment: Your code is a little confusing. Are you sure the example shows things correctly?

Comment: @Takarii I've updated my question to include an example database. Can't just exclude the no values because each service is a separate column of the table and there are a lot of services.